# How to properly use lookahead in Ruby Regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am expecting this to match only the first instance of `<style`, because the second one, after the space has the pattern that I have put in the negative lookahead.

```
"<style type=\"text/html\">ciaoxocs <style />".scan /<style\s?(?!\/>)/
# => ["<style ", "<style"]
```

I want to an explanation for what is happening here, and possibly a better solution to match only the first instance without matching the closing tag with or without space:

```
<style /> or <style/>
```

In regex101.com, it works as expected with other langs:

https://www.regex101.com/r/pW2oM3/1

Comment: Here's one for RUBY regexes: http://rubular.com/

Comment: It is not what I am asking

Comment: It is not an answer.

Comment: Your problem is the optional space. If you want to make the space optional, you also have to add it to the lookahead.

Comment: @MikeK., no, `/<style\s?(?!\s?\/>)/`

Comment: @ndn you are rright, even if I don't understand why my is wrong

Comment: I just wonder if what you are doing can be easier achieved with [Nokogiri](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/).

Comment: Obligatory reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the second match (which comes from `<style />`) is `<style`, (without space) and not `<style` (ending with space; somehow you cannot see the difference here). Your negative lookahead `(?!\/>)` in `/<style\s?(?!\/>)/` only prohibits `\/>` coming right after the substring matching `<style\s?`. If the matched string that corresponds to this part of the regex is `<style` (without the space), then what immediately follows it in the original string is the space (and not `\/>`), so the negative condition is satisfied.

If you are sure that the pattern you want to match always has a space, then you can simply make the space obligatory, and you will get only what you want:

```
"<style type=\"text/html\">ciaoxocs <style />".scan /<style\s(?!\/>)/
# => ["<style "]
```

If you cannot be sure about that, then move the optional space into the negative lookahead.

```
"<style type=\"text/html\">ciaoxocs <style />".scan /<style(?!\s?\/>)/
# => ["<style"]
```

Comment: Why should I hate this? anyway good answer, I have understand what I was missing

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the backtracking mechanism. Let's see the description of what happens with the closing tag:

`<script\s?` matches `"<script "` but the `(?!/>)` fails. In this situation the backtracking mechanism begins and quantifiers give back their characters one by one until the pattern succeeds. In our case, the only possibility is to give back the space from `\s?`.
After this backtracking step, `<script\s?` matches `"<script"` (without the space this time) and the `(?!/>)` condition succeeds with `" />"`.

There are several possibilities to prevent this mechanism:

- using an atomic group `(?>...)` (that forbids backtracking for the sub-pattern once the closing parenthesis is reached): `<script(?>\s?)(?!/>)`
- using a possessive quantifier `?+` (that forbids backtracking for the quantifier): `<script\s?+(?!/>)`
- including the space in the lookahead: `<script(?!\s?/>)\s?`

Answer (score -2):

You probably want use [`String#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-match), instead of `String#scan` which iteratively applies pattern until end of string is reached.

```
> "<style type=\"text/html\">ciaoxocs <style />".match(/<style\s?(?!\/>)/).to_a
=> ["<style "]
```

Comment: it not what I am asking

Comment: Really ? It exactly matches required result [linked](https://www.regex101.com/r/pW2oM3/1) in your question.

Comment: If you did expect different result, put *exactly* which part of the original string should be matched.

Comment: @joanbm The OP is not asking about the result. The OP is asking **what is happening** with the OP's code, and a better way to match only the first one (using `scan`).

Comment: From the OP *"In regex101.com, it works as expected with other langs:"*. He compares apples (single regexp match) with oranges (repeated regexp matching), so it is why gets different results. I find the right answer mention this misunderstanding what `#scan` really does.